Difference in results took from application and via SQL Developer
I am investigating strange problem - when I run SQL query manually via e.g SQL Developer I am getting different result than when application run the same. I know it's impossible but that's what happening.
We have method to get some values from database:
public sizeNotification loadSizeNotificationByTypeAndColor(
            TypeEnum type, String color) {

        if (color == null)
            return loadSizeNotificationByType(type);

        Query q = getSession().getNamedQuery("getNotificationByTypeAndColor");
        q.setString("type", type.getType());
        q.setString("color", color);

        List<SizeNotification> results = q.list();

        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else if (results.size() > 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't have > 1 records in table for Color ");
        } else {
            return results.get(0);
        }
    }

we have named query in this place
getSession().getNamedQuery("getNotificationByTypeAndColor")

which is:
<query name="getNotificationByTypeAndColor">
        <![CDATA[from SizeNotification n where n.type = :type and n.color=:color]]>
    </query>

in logs I can see:
[Worker-2] DEBUG [AbstractBatcher.java:401] - 
    /* named HQL query getNotificationByTypeAndColor */ select
        batchsizen0_.KEY as KEY1_,
        batchsizen0_.ID_TYPE as ID2_1_,
        batchsizen0_.NOTIFICATION as NOTIFICA3_1_,
        batchsizen0_.DATE as DATE4_1_,
        batchsizen0_.COLOR_ID as COLOR5_1_ 
    from
        SIZE_NOTIFICATIONS batchsizen0_ 
    where
        batchsizen0_.TYPE=? 
        and batchsizen0_.COLOR=?

[Worker-2] DEBUG [NullableType.java:133] - binding 'GR' to parameter: 1
[Worker-2] DEBUG [NullableType.java:133] - binding '89' to parameter: 2

[Worker-2] DEBUG [NullableType.java:172] - returning '173' as column: KEY1_
[Worker-2] DEBUG [NullableType.java:172] - returning 'false' as column: NOTIFICA3_1_
[Worker-2] DEBUG [NullableType.java:172] - returning '2024-07-01 11:30:00' as column: DATE4_1_
[Worker-2] DEBUG [NullableType.java:172] - returning '89' as column: COLOR5_1_
[Worker-2] INFO  [ExecutionTimeLoggerInterceptor.java:21] - my.service.externalGen.DataAccessService.loadSizeNotificationByTypeAndColor([GR, 89]), took : 13 ms.

so it's returning
returning 'false' as column: NOTIFICA3_1_

however when I run the same query (getNotificationByTypeAndColor) manually via SQLDeveloper I receive NOTIFICA3_1_ true.
I don't understand from where this missmatch can come from. I should mention that I am using hibernate 3.2. What should I check here, how it can happen?

What is type of SizeNotification. NOTIFICATION ?

It's VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)

Java type is Boolean ? Values have been  inserted by application ?  I think hibernate stores boolean by default as 1 or 0 but it probably depends on version and dialect

@Bartun, it's before any mapping to Java Object. Here is class NullableType https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.2/src/org/hibernate/type/NullableType.java in line 172 there is log, as you can see that already here we have wrong value. It's just from database - before mapping to Java object

log().trace( "returning '" + toString( value ) + "' as column: " + name );
Isn't toString abstract method ?  and  its implemented in certain type ?
I would check that ;)
